# iOS random crash after use removeFromSuperview in swift

Tags: ios, crash

I'm having UICollectionView , and when user select on cell.
I display enlarge image, and one close button to close it.

I'm having trouble here that, i had random crash when i press close button with ClosePreviewImg() func.

Really don't know why, here is my code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


            self.previewingid = FunPics[selectedtab]![indexPath.row]

            var alertfrm = UIView();
            //alertfrm.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
            alertfrm.frame = self.view.frame
            alertfrm.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x000000, alpha: 0.8)
            alertfrm.tag = 201

            var PreviewImg = UIImageView()
            PreviewImg.frame = alertfrm.frame
            PreviewImg.image = UIImage(named: FunPics[selectedtab]![indexPath.row])
            PreviewImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
            PreviewImg.userInteractionEnabled = true
            var taptocopy = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("CopyIt"))
            taptocopy.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            PreviewImg.addGestureRecognizer(taptocopy)

            alertfrm.addSubview(PreviewImg)


            var CloseBtn = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
            CloseBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "RobotoSlab-Regular", size: 15)
            CloseBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x000000, alpha: 0.4)
            CloseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            CloseBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1
            CloseBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xffffff, alpha: 0.4).CGColor
            CloseBtn.frame = CGRectMake(60, 10, 50, 30)
            CloseBtn.setTitle("Close", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CloseBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CloseBtn.addTarget(self, action: "ClosePreviewImg", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            alertfrm.addSubview(CloseBtn)


            // constraint
            //CopyBtn.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            CloseBtn.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

            /*
            var CC = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CopyBtn, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alertfrm, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
            var CW = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CopyBtn, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 50)
            var CR = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CopyBtn, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: CloseBtn, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -5)
            var CB = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CopyBtn, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alertfrm, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)
            alertfrm.addConstraints([CW,CR,CB])*/

            var CC1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CloseBtn, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alertfrm, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            var CW1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CloseBtn, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 50)
            //var CL = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CloseBtn, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: CopyBtn, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            var CB1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: CloseBtn, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: alertfrm, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)
            alertfrm.addConstraints([CC1,CW1,CB1])

            self.view.addSubview(alertfrm)

    }


    func ClosePreviewImg()
    {
        self.view.viewWithTag(201)?.removeFromSuperview()
        NSLog("ClosePreviewImg")

    }
```

Here is a part my error log report after use removeFromSuperView()
(can't paste all of it, because too long)

```
Objective: {objective 0x79ec0660: <1:-1.55701e-05> + <1:9.85447e-08>*0x79ea3b50.negError{id: 134} + <1:-9.85447e-08>*0x79ea3b50.posErrorMarker{id: 133} + <1:0>*UIButton:0x79ea1e50'changekey'.Width{id: 10} + <1:1>*tempToBeOptimizedToZero{id: 848}}
Oct 28 00:14:47 *-MacBook-Pro.local KeyboardExt[1832]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0x79eaefd0>{ Rows:
        0x79e94730.negError{id: 126} == 600 + -0.00277778*UIButton:0x79ea1e50'changekey'.Width{id: 10} + 1*0x79e94730.posErrorMarker{id: 125}
        0x79ea3610.negError{id: 130} == 179 + -0.00277778*UIButton:0x79fee8e0'happy'.Width{id: 16} + 1*0x79ea3610.posErrorMarker{id: 129}
        0x79ea3650.negError{id: 132} == 89 + 1*0x79eadbd0.marker{id: 17} + -1*0x79eadd70.marker{id: 19} + -1*0x79eb4380.marker{id: 122} + 1*0x79ea3650.posErrorMarker{id: 131}
        0x79ea3b90.negError{id: 136} == 89 + 1*0x79eade50.marker{id: 27} + -1*0x79eadee0.marker{id: 29} + -1*0x79eb4380.marker{id: 122} + 1*0x79ea3b90.posErrorMarker{id: 135}
        0x79ea3ec0.negError{id: 138} == 173 + -0.00277778*UIButton:0x7a18c2a0'angry'.Width{id: 36} + 1*0x79ea3ec0.posErrorMarker{id: 137}


libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x3387694:  movl   $0x80148, %eax
0x3387699:  calll  0x33894dc                 ; _sysenter_trap
0x338769e:  jae    0x33876ae                 ; __pthread_kill + 26
0x33876a0:  calll  0x33876a5                 ; __pthread_kill + 17
0x33876a5:  popl   %edx
0x33876a6:  movl   0x697b(%edx), %edx
0x33876ac:  jmpl   *%edx
0x33876ae:  retl   
0x33876af:  nop
```

Comment: Can you add the stack trace for the crash?

Comment: stack trace ? the crash happen after i press close button and ClosePreviewImg() was called

Comment: @TomSawyer it appears that you remove the view with tag `201` from its superview, but you do not remove `NSLayoutConstraint`s related to that view and AutoLayout throws an exception when tries to layout the views.

Comment: I don't think so, UIKit automatically removes contraints associated with a view when this view is moved out of view hierarchy.

Comment: I realize this isn't your question, and I almost just clicked away, but I have to say.  Please don't hardcode tags.  In fact, don't use tags at all except for some extenuating circumstances (ie: multiple alertView responses in one VC).  It is very difficult to read and will cause a slew of problems later on.  Good luck finding your bug! :)

Comment: @Vinzzz yes you are right. But perhaps somewhere else in the code there are constraints added in relation the `201` view. I don't see any flaws in the pasted code, just posting a suggestion.

Comment: @BartekChlebek i just tried to add code to remove constraints before removefromsuperview         self.view.viewWithTag(201)?.removeConstraints(self.view.viewWithTag(201)!.constraints())
but didn't worked.

Comment: @TomSawyer the constraint `CW1` should be added to the `CloseBtn` not the `alertfrm`

Comment: @BartekChlebek ? CW1 is required to fixed with for CloseBtn button = 50. I tried to remove CW1 and all constraints too, but error still there, i don't think the trouble is come from constraints of my button.

Comment: @TomSawyer you're right. It doesn't make any difference. Does the crash happen as well if you call `ClosePreviewImg()` without pressing the button? For example if you dispatch it to be called after a second?

Comment: @BartekChlebek Yes, it's will happen too if i call ClosePreviewImg() function instead of press an button. But it seems take longer time to crash. With press button, after close/open about 5-6 times, crash will happen, but if i call function (open and close image immediately) , it took 10-15 times to crash.

Comment: @TomSawyer just to be sure, you only use `201` tag for this `alertfrm`, right? Is there any possibility that `self.view.viewWithTag(201)` in `ClosePreviewImg()` returns anything else than `alertfrm`?

Comment: @BartekChlebek Hi, i think i just found how to avoid crash. When i remove the line `CloseBtn.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` and remove all constraint added to CloseBtn. The crash didn't happen. If i don't remove `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` line (even without constraint, or added constraint), crash will happen. That's really weird ??!

Comment: @TomSawyer yeah it is! But I'm glad you found a way to avoid crashing :) If you find out anything more, please let us know

Comment: @BartekChlebek but it didn't make me satisfied now, because i really don't know how to fix it, if i don't use `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` i can't use constraint and my button can be center :|

Comment: Then, instead of using `viewWithTag` , try using a local `weak` variable. (`weak var alertFrm : UIView?`). this way, it's automatically deallocated once no superview holds a reference to it. (after calling `removeFromSuperview`). Cleaner code

Comment: @Vinzzz Many tks for all of your replies. I fixed my bug. The trouble is constraints, i clear and rewrite all constraints and there's no random crash anymore. (i still using `viewWithtag`)